# Google Api Gateway with Cloud Run CORS

Tags: cors, google-cloud-run, google-api-gateway

Is there a way to enable Cors in the Google Api gateway config for Cloud Run services?

I enabled Cors in the service themselves, but I always get

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'xxx' from origin 'http://localhost:4200/' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Wondering if the Api Gateway is the problem, because calling the cloud run service directly works fine.

Comment: This is a highly voted feature, it's not available yet. https://groups.google.com/g/api-gateway-users/c/9CwyQr1c420

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could overcome the missing functionality

- by adding a load balancer
- create a custom header [Guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/custom-headers)

You just need to add the "Access-Control-Origin" header:

```
Allow all
```

`Access-Control-Origin:'*'`

See steps for [API Gateway and Load balancer](https://medium.com/swlh/google-api-gateway-and-load-balancer-cdn-9692b7a976df).

Comment: Seems I am inching closer, now I get Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost' that is not equal to the supplied origin. (http://localhost:4200). I am guessing this has to do with the cloudrun service. Investigating, thanks for your help!

Comment: Now I am getting: from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: It seems the issue was due to Firebase authentication setup globally instead of per method. Changing it to Method worked.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with GET request in nodejs+cloudrun. I tried adding OPTIONS in code as well as in the specs for preflight but no luck so far.  Can anyone please help how you resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Adding options for the path fixes the issue

```
x-google-endpoints:
  - name: ...name here...
    allowCors: True
paths:
  /tasks:
    post:
      ...
    options:
      description: "Cors associated request to tasks"
      operationId: "tasks CORS"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Allow"
        401:
          description: "Not allowed"
```